# AxesStyle with ComplexListPlot gives error when attempting to increase font size

Tags: plotting

If I generate some data and use `ComplexListPlot`

```
x = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 25];
y = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 25];
data = x + I*y;
ComplexListPlot[data]
```

I get a nice picture.

[image: ComplexListPlot]

I can change the color and thickness of the axes like

```
ComplexListPlot[data, AxesStyle -> {Directive[Orange], Directive[Black, Thick]}]
```

to get another nice picture

[image: ComplexListPlot with different axes]

But if I try `Directive[Orange, 12]` (or similar) taken directly from the [AxesStyle](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AxesStyle.html) documentation to try and increase the font size I get an error.

For example

```
ComplexListPlot[data, AxesStyle -> {Directive[Orange, 20], Directive[Black, Thick]}]
```

gives an error message `20 is not a graphics directive.`

The strange thing is that it actually changes the figure correctly.
[image: ComplexListPlot with error]

What's going on? (This is with version 12.2)

Comment: As a workaround, change the `20` to `FontSize -> 20`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of putting 20 directly into the `Directive`, write a rule `FontSize -> 20`:

```
ComplexListPlot[data, 
 AxesStyle -> {Directive[Orange, FontSize -> 20], 
   Directive[Black, Thick]}]
```

That will give you the desired output without the error box.

I don't know why AxesStyle for ComplexListPlot seems to work differently from other plotting functions. I tried `AxesStyle -> Directive[Orange, FontSize -> 20]` with others, and it gives the output you mentioned even in version 12.3.